# How to check-out a file from sharepoint document library using curl?

Tags: sharepoint, soap, curl

It is possible to checkin a file to sharepoint document library using curl with the following command as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442467/how-to-auto-upload-and-check-in-the-files-to-sharepoint-using-curl) :

```
curl --ntlm --user username:password --upload-file file.txt https://mysharepointserver.com/sites/mysite/myfile.txt -k
```

But how to checkout the file first(using curl) from the document library?

I tried one method by passing SOAPAction checkoutfile headers and data as follows, but it had no effect eventhough the server returned response: '200 OK'

```
curl --ntlm --user username:password -d @soapdata.xml -H "SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CheckOutFile"  -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" https://mysharepointserver.com/sites/mysite/myfile.txt -k
```

soapdata.xml contains the SOAP data needed for checkout as described by WSDL. Is there something wrong in above command or is there a simpler way to do this with CURL like the checkin case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found from an [example](http://code.huypv.net/2012/01/test-soap-server-with-curl-command.html) that, with SOAP approach, the URL in CURL command should be the path of the sharepoint site Lists.asmx and not the URL of file to be checked out. The file URL need to be only in the pageUrl field in soapdata xml as follows:

```
curl --ntlm --user username:password -d @soapdata.xml -H "SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CheckOutFile" -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -k -v https://mysharepointserver.com/sites/mysite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx
```

where contents of soapdata.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <CheckOutFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <pageUrl>https://mysharepointserver.com/sites/mysite/myfile.txt</pageUrl>
      <checkoutToLocal>true</checkoutToLocal>
      <lastmodified/>
    </CheckOutFile>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```