# Performing multiple requests using curl, with different options

Tags: bash, sharepoint, curl

I'm trying to use curl to upload a file to sharepoint. I can do this successfully in three steps (ie. 3 separate invocations of curl to check the file out, upload it, and check it back in), using the suggestions in the following post:

[How to check-out a file from sharepoint document library using curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772564/how-to-check-out-a-file-from-sharepoint-document-library-using-curl)

My individual requests look like:

```
# Checkout the index.html file
curl --ntlm --user ${USER} \
    --data @- \
    -H "SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CheckOutFile" \
    -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" \
    ${SHAREPOINT}/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx << EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <CheckOutFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <pageUrl>${FILE}</pageUrl>
      <checkoutToLocal>false</checkoutToLocal>
      <lastmodified/>
    </CheckOutFile>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
EOF

# upload the file
curl --ntlm -u ${USER} \
    -T HTML/2015/index.html \
    ${FOLDER}

curl --ntlm --user ${USER} \
    --data @- \
    -H "SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CheckInFile" \
    -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" \
    ${SHAREPOINT}/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx << EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CheckInFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <pageUrl>${FILE}</pageUrl>
      <comment>Automagic update</comment>
      <checkinType>0</checkinType>
    </CheckInFile>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
EOF
```

Unfortunately, this results in cUrl asking me for my password 3 times (and it's a long password! :-) ). I also don't like the idea of a .netrc file, since writing passwords to disk is not a great idea.

So, what I thought I might be able to do is combine all of the requests into a single command line, setting and deleting headers as necessary, supplying the request bodies as appropriate using bash process substitution, etc.

```
curl --ntlm --user ${USER} \
    --trace-ascii publish.log \
    --data @<(echo "$CHECKOUT") \
    -H "SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CheckOutFile" \
    -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" \
    ${SHAREPOINT}/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx \
    -H "SOAPAction:" \
    -H "Content-Type:" \
    -T HTML/2015/index.html \
    ${FOLDER} \
    --data @<(echo "$CHECKIN") \
    -H "SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CheckInFile" \
    -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" \
    ${SHAREPOINT}/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx
```

Unfortunately, what happens is that cUrl seems to process all of the options at once, and only then attempt to request the URL's, resulting in options for one URL overwriting options for another URL, and ultimately nothing working. A snippet from the log file:

```
> 0000: PUT /xxx/xxx/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx HTTP/1.1
> 0033: Authorization: NTLM AAAAAAAAAAA=
> 0075: User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> 008e: Host: example.com
> 00a8: Accept: */*
> 00b5: SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CheckOu
> 00f5: tFile
> 00fc: Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
> 0123: SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CheckIn
> 0163: File
> 0169: Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
> 0190: Content-Length: 0
> 01a3: Expect: 100-continue
```

Notice the duplicated SOAPAction header, while I was hoping to only have the first options applied.

Is there any way to say "stop processing options now, do this URL, then carry on"?

Comment: If typing password is your only concern, you can prompt for the password and read it in a variable and use it in curl command as like below.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, command line arguments show up in the results of commands like "ps", and "top", etc, which could expose the passwords of anyone using that technique.

Comment: @RoganDawes I'm trying the same thing and stuck at something. Nothing's working. If you're fine, could you please share your complete code in a git or something? This will help me a lot. I'm completely new to this and trying to learn.

Comment: I never came to a satisfactory conclusion in this matter.

Taking a quick look at the curl man page, I think I'd carefully check the --config option to see how that worked, and if I could execute a series of requests with different options.

Comment: I just learned of the curl `--next` option, which seems to address exactly this issue:
https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2020/03/02/curl-ootw-next/
I have not tested it, as I no longer have access to a SharePoint instance, but that's where I'd look if I still needed this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If typing password three times is your only concern, you can prompt for the password and read it in a variable and use it in curl command as like below.

```
echo "Password: "
read -s PASSWORD
# Checkout the index.html file
curl --ntlm --user ${USER}:${PASSWORD} \
    --data @- \
    -H "SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CheckOutFile" \
    -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" \
    ${SHAREPOINT}/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx << EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CheckOutFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <pageUrl>${FILE}</pageUrl>
      <checkoutToLocal>false</checkoutToLocal>
      <lastmodified/>
    </CheckOutFile>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
EOF

# upload the file
curl --ntlm -u ${USER}:${PASSWORD} \
    -T HTML/2015/index.html \
    ${FOLDER}

curl --ntlm --user ${USER}:${PASSWORD} \
    --data @- \
    -H "SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CheckInFile" \
    -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" \
    ${SHAREPOINT}/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx << EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CheckInFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <pageUrl>${FILE}</pageUrl>
      <comment>Automagic update</comment>
      <checkinType>2</checkinType>
    </CheckInFile>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
EOF
```

Comment: I'm not too fond of leaving passwords in command lines either. While I trust that my own machine has not been compromised (otherwise I'd wipe it and reinstall), I feel it is good practice to avoid such things. Hence the reason to avoid the password in a netrc file as well.

Comment: @vijayalakshmid, Can you please advice me on how to implement the checkin part using curl from R system function?