# Unable to upload files to Microsoft Sharepoint from unix server using cURL command

Tags: shell, unix, sharepoint-2010

I'm unable to upload the file from unix box to Microsoft sharepoint URL

The commands are executed, but the file is not getting uploaded to the URL

curl --ntlm --user nikhil.viswanathan@wincshare.onmicrosoft.com:******** --upload-file test_file.xls https://wincshare.sharepoint.com/BOCC%20Documents/test_file.xls

```
-bash-3.2$ curl -T test_file.xls -o test_file.xls -u "nikhil.viswanathan@wincshare.onmicrosoft.com" "https://wincshare.sharepoint.com/BOCC%20Documents/"
Enter host password for user 'nikhil.viswanathan@wincshare.onmicrosoft.com':
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2705    0    13  100  2692     10   2135  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 15742
-bash-3.2$
```

But, the file test_file.xls, is not getting uploaded.

Please help me out here

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Is the URL "https://wincshare.sharepoint.com/BOCC%20Documents/" expecting a PUT (not POST) of the file with no other parameters ?

Somehow I seriously doubt that, but I don't do MSFT stuff.

I'm also doubting a bit the use of -o with the same filename as the file you're trying to upload. [Your output is going to overwrite the file it is uploading]

To add the fields and push curl into POST mode there are options such as the -d and/or -F (see curl man page).

Also see here: [How to auto upload and check in the files to sharepoint using curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442467/how-to-auto-upload-and-check-in-the-files-to-sharepoint-using-curl) as I guess it might well be the same thing you're trying to achieve.